# Insert SPAN value to DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried many ways to insert the value from SPAN to DB? The value displayed into span is from Javascript. Currently when i run, 0.00 from both UP and TP will get displayed with values from javascript functions. And when i insert into MYSQL Database, i get all other data inserted except for the values from UP and TP. I am using input type = "hidden" to just pass the value. THis is my code. Can anyone help? Thank you.

```
 <p></p><div><b>UnitPrice: <span id="UP">0.00</span> </b></div><p>
 <p></p><div><b>TotalPrice: <span id="TP">0.00</span> </b></div><p>

 <input type="hidden" name="UnitPrice" value="', document.getElementById("UP").value '"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="TotalPrice" value="', document.getElementById("TP").value '"/>

 $UnitPrice = (trim($_POST['UnitPrice']));
 $TotalPrice= (trim($_POST['TotalPrice']));

 $query = "INSERT INTO `OrderItem` (`UnitPrice`, `TotalPrice`) VALUES ('$UnitPrice','$TotalPrice')";
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die($query."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUP(str) {
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5   
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){   
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getunitprice.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


function multiply(Quantity) {
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML)*Quantity;
    document.getElementById("TP").innerHTML = totalPrice;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting *anything* in your database at the moment? Also, can you post how you are updating the hidden fields and how you are submitting the form please?

Comment: Please specify what kind of SPAN you are talking about is it a parsed through JavaScript script html entity SPAN?  Do not use DB, please use no short : use my SQL database.  What is the movement involved in the "into".  Your HTML code is not valid, please use <script type="text/javascript">.  Why should you parse you HTML DOM?  Please use "<?php".  That could help me to understand your view.

Comment: @Fluffeh i have editted my question. as mentioned, im using the hidden field to pass value. Is that the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is javascript and you cannot do it like that.

When you get `<span id="UP">0.00</span>` you can also add that hidden element with that value, add `ID` to hidden elements` and modify your javascript function to add values to those hidden elements

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUP(str) {
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5   
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){   
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("UnitPrice").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getunitprice.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}


function multiply(Quantity) {
    var totalPrice = parseFloat(document.getElementById("UP").innerHTML)*Quantity;
    document.getElementById("TP").innerHTML = totalPrice;
    document.getElementById("TotalPrice").value = totalPrice;
}
</script>

<p></p><div><b>UnitPrice: <span id="UP">0.00</span> </b><input type="hidden" name="UnitPrice" id="UnitPrice" value=""/></div><p>
<p></p><div><b>TotalPrice: <span id="TP">0.00</span> </b><input type="hidden" name="TotalPrice" id="TotalPrice" value=""/></div><p>
```

Comment: When i do this, i get error. UnitPrice:
Notice: Undefined variable: up in C:\xampp\htdocs\addorderitem.php on line 158

TotalPrice:
Notice: Undefined variable: tp in C:\xampp\htdocs\addorderitem.php on line 159

Comment: as I said, assume `$up` and `$tp`, you have to define those variables, updated the code.

Comment: thats doesn't work as i have UP and TP from a function. added the function codes in my question.

Comment: you must be getting `0.00` from somewhere, where do you get them from?

Comment: the 0.00 is hardcoded but according to the function, when the product is selected and the quantity is entered it will change accordingly. so i want this value to be updated in to my database.                                                   UnitPrice: 4.50

TotalPrice: 22.5

Comment: so you may want to post the javascript function that updates that span

Comment: updated my answer, you should add `ID`'s to those hidden elements and modify your functions to add values to those hidden elements same as it updates your `span`'s

Comment: if you pasted the correct javascript you use, it should work.

Comment: yes i pasted the one with your edits. since its not adding anything, in my db it shows as 0.00

Comment: nope doesnt help. It seems to be not passing the value from jquery result to mysql...$UnitPrice = (trim($_POST['UnitPrice']));
$TotalPrice= (trim($_POST['TotalPrice']));

Comment: you don't have jQuery there, I have tested the code and works fine.

Comment: you are able to post the values to db? can you enlighten me?

Comment: no, I said my code work fine and are passing to next page. I cannot determine your problem without seeing nothing in action.